# How to get values orientation of end effector pose?

Tags: ros, pose, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first, I am so sorry because my english is not good.

Next, I'm working with robot arm 5DOF. I want to move end effector pose. i can move along x y z asix but i dont know how to get values orientation of eef?

i got pose with getCurrentPose() and maybe i can get orientation with getCurrentRPY()???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326239/how-to-get-values-orientation-of-end-effector-pose-?/) by [TardiSs](https://answers.ros.org/users/39073/tardiss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it!
I used " std::vector orientation = move_group.getCurrentRPY(); " to get vector 3 elements roll pitch yaw. After that convert RPY to Quaternion and set this values to target_pose.

---

Originally posted by [TardiSs](https://answers.ros.org/users/39073/tardiss/) with karma: 16 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-20**:
Wouldn't just looking up the TF to your EEF's frame get you this information? That would immediately be in a format that would be usable.

**Comment by [TardiSs](https://answers.ros.org/users/39073/tardiss/) on 2019-06-20**:
I thought about that way but i do not know how to looking up the tf to eef's frame get this information?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-20**:
Would you know how to lookup a transform?

**Comment by [TardiSs](https://answers.ros.org/users/39073/tardiss/) on 2019-06-20**:
No, I do not know. TT

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-20**:
Then I would suggest to do the [TF2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials). The 3rd one ("writing a TF listener") should clarify things for you.

**Comment by [TardiSs](https://answers.ros.org/users/39073/tardiss/) on 2019-06-20**:
Thank you so much!